# Minecraft server clear already loaded .class files from JAR plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, bukkit-vault

So my minecraft server has an economy plugin I've been working on. After battling a couple of days, I realised this is a common problem with Java that it won't unload the classes which are already loaded. So when I tried the plugin on a fresh server instance, it was working correct.

My question is how can I fix the original server? I tried deleting the updated JAR file from that server, ran and stopped the server as a guess that it'd remove the pre-loaded classes but instead that generated the files related to the previous version of plugin, even though the plugin's JAR wasn't in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what is not working? If it's crashing, please edit this and add a bit of the console log where the error is happening.

If it's working properly on another server make sure the JARs are all compiled from the latest source.

There could also be a conflict with another plugin. Try disabling all other plugins and see if it works than.

Comment: Ha! I just realized my profile pic is my crazy old MC skin. I need to update that...

Comment: The updated plugin source is not being picked by the server. And since it's working properly the JAR is updated already. I've checked the JAR with a decompiler before too as well. I'll try the last part.. Sleepy AF right now. Mushroom cows are good haha!

Comment: You never know- is the JAR in the plugins folder? Or is there another JAR with a similar name?

Comment: Holy shit! I figured out the problem. I can't believe I did this mistake. I made a previous plugin before and idk how it has the old version of this plugin which has been driving me crazy, and it is in the same folder.

Comment: Ha! So I guess it was a conflict with that old plugin?

Comment: Yeah, old files of this plugin existed in another plugin that I made.